# Why isn't JSF setting an id automatically?

Tags: jsf-2

Here is my xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
.error {
    background-color: #fdd;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:messages style="color: orange" />
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{myBacking.um}" required="true" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBacking.acme}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I tested with mojarra 2.0.9 and mojarra 2.1.8, and both doesn't generate an id for the `h:inputText` component.
Is it a bug in JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mojarra will only set the ID if the enduser has specified it by itself or if the component has client behaviors specified (by `<f:ajax>`).

Here's an extract of relevance of the [`HtmlBasicRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.7/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#HtmlBasicRenderer.shouldWriteIdAttribute%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) source code:

```
protected String writeIdAttributeIfNecessary(FacesContext context, ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) {
    String id = null;
    if (shouldWriteIdAttribute(component)) {
        try {
            writer.writeAttribute("id", id = component.getClientId(context), "id");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.WARNING)) {
                String message = MessageUtils.getExceptionMessageString (MessageUtils.CANT_WRITE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_MESSAGE_ID, e.getMessage());
                logger.warning(message);
            }
        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

And, note the comments

```
protected boolean shouldWriteIdAttribute(UIComponent component) {

    // By default we only write the id attribute if:
    //
    // - We have a non-auto-generated id, or...
    // - We have client behaviors.
    //
    // We assume that if client behaviors are present, they
    // may need access to the id (AjaxBehavior certainly does).

    String id;
    return (null != (id = component.getId()) &&
                (!id.startsWith(UIViewRoot.UNIQUE_ID_PREFIX) ||
                    ((component instanceof ClientBehaviorHolder) &&
                      !((ClientBehaviorHolder)component).getClientBehaviors().isEmpty())));
}
```

So, that's expected behavior.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks! Is this specified behaviour? I actually ran into this problem when I was testing `<o:highlight />` from OmniFaces, cause it only works on components that have an id. Should I open an issue? :)

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Will look at it tonight or tomorrow. Feel free to post an issue so that it can be tracked.